# How to know which Rest controller method called using HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse object?

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I am using `HandlerInterceptor` (`import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;`) to get the `Request` and `Response` Attributes and `Header` information using `preHandle, postHandle` methods.

Now I want to know the name of the method called of Controller. Is there any way if we can get that info using `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse` object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `Object handler` to get the details of method invocation. See the below code:

```
@Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
```

and

```
public static String getMethodName(Object handler) {
        String methodName = null;
        if(handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            methodName = method.getMethod().getName();
        }
        return methodName;
    }
```